# Bootstrap Jumbotrons side by side

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a webpage, the landing page has two portals. I would like to use jombotrons to be used as the portals. I would like to have two jumbotrons side by side. I thought if I put them inside a row div, and gave them col-mid-6 class this would give me the desired affect. However, they just span across the page, and then stack. Any help would be very much appreciated. I'm very new to css and bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center col-mid-6">
            <h1>Become Awesome</h1>
            <p>Here you will learn how to become awesome.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" href="{% url 'awesome_info' %}">More Info</a>
        </div>

        <div class="jumbotron text-center col-mid-6">
            <h1>Here you will learn how to become super rad.</h1>
            <p>Tubular dude.</p>
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'rad_info' %}" role="button">More Info</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct class is [`col-md-6`](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

With that your jumbotron will be equal widths like in *[here](http://jsfiddle.net/FQWzm/embedded/result/)*

If you want the height to be equal too, give your `container` class a css property such as:

```
.container{
    display: flex
}
```

For the result to be [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/FQWzm/1/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your divs. Bootstrap calls for a `col-md-6` class, not a `col-mid-6` class.

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center col-md-6"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your `div.container` into a `div.row` then, write this css property

`.container{
    display: flex
}`